# Seaborn swarmplot break into lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, swarmplot

I'm trying to make this `swarmplot` with `seaborn`

My problem is that the swarms are too wide. I want to be able to break them up into rows of maximum 3 dots per row

## This is my code:

```py
# Import modules
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
###

# Import and clead dataset
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amirnakar/scratchboard/master/Goodreads/goodreads_library_export.csv"
Books = pd.read_csv(url)
Books = Books[Books['Date Read'].notna()]   # Remove NA

Books['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(             # Convert to dates
    Books['Date Read'],
    format='%YYYY%mm%dd', 
    errors='coerce')

Books['Year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(Books['Date Read']).year # Take only years
Books[['Year', 'Date Read']]                 # merge the years in
###

# Calculate mean rate by year
RateMeans = (Books["My Rating"].groupby(Books["Year"]).mean())
Years = list(RateMeans.index.values)
Rates = list(RateMeans)
RateMeans = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Years': Years,
     'Rates': Rates
    })
###

# Plot
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))

## Violin Plot:
plot = sns.violinplot(
    data=Books, 
    x = "Year", 
    y = 'My Rating', 
    ax=ax,
    color = "white", 
    inner=None,
    #palette=colors_from_values(ArrayRates[:,1], "Blues")
    )

## Swarm Plot
plot = sns.swarmplot(
    data=Books, 
    x = "Year", 
    y = 'My Rating', 
    ax=ax,
    hue = "My Rating",
    size = 10
    )
    
## Style
    
### Title
ax.text(x=0.5, y=1.1, s='Book Ratings: Distribution per Year', fontsize=32, weight='bold', ha='center', va='bottom', transform=ax.transAxes)
ax.text(x=0.5, y=1.05, s='Source: Goodreads.com (amirnakar)', fontsize=24, alpha=0.75, ha='center', va='bottom', transform=ax.transAxes)



### Axis
ax.set(xlim=(4.5, None), ylim=(0,6))
#ax.set_title('Book Ratings: Distribution per Year \n', fontsize = 32)
ax.set_ylabel('Rating (out of 5 stars)', fontsize = 24)
ax.set_xlabel('Year', fontsize = 24)
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticks().astype(int), size=20)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticks(), size=20)

### Legend
plot.legend(loc="lower center", ncol = 5 )

### Colour pallete
colorset = ["#FAFF04", "#FFD500", "#9BFF00", "#0099FF", "#000BFF"]
colorset.reverse()
sns.set_palette(sns.color_palette(colorset))


# Save the plot
#plt.show(plot)
plt.savefig("Rate-Python.svg", format="svg")
```

## This is the output:

[image]

## What I want to have happen:

I want to be able to define that **each row of dots should have a *maximum*** of 3, if it's more, than break it into a new row. I demonstrate it here (done manually in PowerPoint) on two groups, but I want it for the entire plot

#### BEFORE:

[image: BEFORE]

#### AFTER:

[image]

Comment: Such an option is not supported in seaborn's swarmplot.

Comment: Do you know of a good alternative? maybe with `matplotlib`?

Comment: No, I don't think there is. Peeking into seaborn's [source code](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/9425588d3498755abd93960df4ab05ec1a8de3ef/seaborn/categorical.py#L284) could give some hints.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is way beyond my level right now.

Comment: Since you have discrete y values, it should be relatively easy to count the number of observations for each value and adjust some up or down before plotting to get the result you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an attempt to relocate the dots a bit upward/downward. The value for `delta` comes from experimenting.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Import and clea dataset
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amirnakar/scratchboard/master/Goodreads/goodreads_library_export.csv"
Books = pd.read_csv(url)
Books = Books[Books['Date Read'].notna()]  # Remove NA
Books['Year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(Books['Date Read']).year  # Take only years
# Calculate mean rate by year
RatePerYear = Books[["My Rating", "Year"]].groupby("Year")["My Rating"].value_counts()

modified_ratings = []
delta = 0.2  # distance to move overlapping ratings
for (year, rating), count in RatePerYear.iteritems():
    higher = max(0, ((count - 3) + 1) // 2)
    lower = max(0, (count - 3) // 2)
    modified_ratings.append([year, rating, count - higher - lower])
    for k in range((higher + 2) // 3):
        modified_ratings.append([year, rating + (k + 1) * delta, 3 if (k + 1) * 3 <= higher else higher % 3])
    for k in range((lower + 2) // 3):
        modified_ratings.append([year, rating - (k + 1) * delta, 3 if (k + 1) * 3 <= lower else lower % 3])
modified_ratings = np.array(modified_ratings)
modified_ratings_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Year': np.repeat(modified_ratings[:, 0].astype(int), modified_ratings[:, 2].astype(int)),
     'My Rating': np.repeat(modified_ratings[:, 1], modified_ratings[:, 2].astype(int))})
modified_ratings_df['Rating'] = modified_ratings_df['My Rating'].round().astype(int)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
sns.violinplot(data=Books, x="Year", y='My Rating', ax=ax, color="white", inner=None)
palette = ["#FAFF04", "#FFD500", "#9BFF00", "#0099FF", "#000BFF"].reverse()
sns.swarmplot(data=modified_ratings_df, x="Year", y='My Rating', ax=ax, hue="Rating", size=10, palette=palette)

ax.set(xlim=(4.5, None), ylim=(0, 6))
ax.legend(loc="lower center", ncol=5)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.swarmplot limiting row widths to 3]